# Returning a value with psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
id_of_new_row = cursor.lastrowid()
```

in which I get the id of the newly created or modified row.  But this isn't available through psycopg2.  Alternatively, I've tried this:

```
id_of_new_row = cursor.execute('INSERT INTO this_table (value1, value2, value3) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) RETURNING id', (some_value1, some_value2, some_value3))
```

which doesn't work, probably because it won't know the id until after the commit is made...

Help!

Comment: What kind of ID you're trying to get - OID or the value of a field declared SERIAL?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm new.  This is a django project, and django sets up the postgres database with syncdb based on my models.  I'm not sure if django declares OID during table creation automatically.  I need the primary key of each row, which is auto-generated as "id" by django, unless otherwise specified. I'll do some reading.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sure it will, it'll know the ID as soon as the command finishes, that's how RETURNING is implemented. You need to actually fetch it though, so something like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO .... RETURNING id")
id_of_new_row = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

should work in your scenario.

Comment: is index  the only way to fetch values from the execute query result. Is three any way to get value ? like row.id ?

Answer (score 3):

RETURNING works on Postgresql >= 8.2